# Multiple variables through COM ports

Tags: matlab, serial-port, arduino, simulink

I want to send and receive multiple variables through COM ports between [Simulink](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simulink) and Arduino. Is this possible? If it is, how can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

I found this: [Arduino support from Simulink](http://www.mathworks.nl/academia/arduino-software/arduino-simulink.html)

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't have any experience in Simulink, I just found that page and thought it might be useful.